# further expldoe on string datatype pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have df where I have the column called data. In the data column we can expect the single values per `identifier_filed` column  or list values. This is shown as `[ ]`brackets under the data column. For example `Allegren` under the `values` column can have different `data` type, but this specific `identifie_field` has only one value but other  `identifie_field` can more than one .

Moreover`physical_form` value can have multiple `data` type values also. I would like to explode on `data` column and presnt each value as a seperate row.

schema of the df:

```
root
 |-- identifier_field: string (nullable = true)
 |-- values: string (nullable = false)
 |-- data: string (nullable = true)
 |-- locale: string (nullable = true)
 |-- scope: string (nullable = true)
```

How it looks now:
[image]

Desired OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Can you supply an example of the result you're looking for? what does it mean "to explode on `data`"?

Comment: I modified the post, thanks

Comment: ok, now can you specify and show code of what you've tried so far and how you reached the place that you are in it? you can refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: well, I dont have further code. Till this result I used `explode` but now i cant anymore since `data` is string type. I guess I need to change the type. but I could not. I defined new `schmea` to apply to exisitng `df` but dont know how

Comment: amm alright, you `df` is a `dataframe` I'll asume, can you add a print of your `dataframe `instead of an image? or is your data is in a `String` variable?

Comment: its in a string variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251289/discussion-between-lidor-eliyahu-shelef-and-greencolor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative solution without `udf`.

```
df = (df
      .withColumn('data', F.when(F.col('data').substr(0, 1) != '[', 
                                 F.concat(F.lit('["'), F.col('data'), F.lit('"]')))
                           .otherwise(F.col('data')))
      .withColumn('data', F.from_json('data', 'array<string>'))
      .select(F.explode_outer('data'))
)
```

First `when` statement might require a change based on what other data you have in the  `data` column. The reason is the first row is not a array looking string, so you need to align all string to be the array like string. Then, you can use `from_json` to convert it to `ArrayType` which then you can do `explode` on.

Comment: thank you so much, I spent on this 6h. could you please explain first 3 lines of the code. what you do with `[ ]`

Comment: when you said that first `when` might need modification because of the `data` column, do you mean that I might have some data with different kind of separator (like `,`,`{` ,`;`)

Comment: Your first row in `data` column has a value `no`. This is not a valid array shape and need to convert it as `["no"]` to use `from_json` function.  The reason I said you might need to change the `when` statement is if you have a data like `[x` or `"x"`, then my code won't work. because it will result in `[["x"]` and `[""x""]` which are both not a valid array shape, hence the next `from_json` will fail.

Comment: First 3 lines is doing IF your string is not starting with `[`, add `["` on the left and `"]` on the right of the value. Otherwise, keep it as it is.  This is to try to align all the values in `data` column to be array-like string.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: Without UDF**

```
df.withColumn("data", split(col("data"), ","))
.withColumn("data", explode_outer("data"))
.withColumn("data", regexp_replace(col("data"), '\"|\[|\]','')).show()
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|    identifier_field|              values|    data|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|PCR-0020779-SAMKG...|prohibited_restri...|      no|
|PCR-0020779-SAMKG...|       physical_form|crystals|
|PCR-0020779-SAMKG...|       physical_form|  powder|
|PCR-0020779-SAMKG...|      region_country| Emea_EU|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

You can use UDF to convert string value  to array in column `data` and then explode.

```
data = [("PCR-0020779-SAMKGO-FH", "prohibited_restricted_authorised_chemicals", "no"),
        ("PCR-0020779-SAMKGO-FH", "physical_form", '["crystals", "powder"]'),
        ("PCR-0020779-SAMKGO-FH", "region_country", ' ["Emea_EU"]')]
columns = ["identifier_field", "values", "data"]

spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
    
+---------------------+------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|identifier_field     |values                                    |data                  |
+---------------------+------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|PCR-0020779-SAMKGO-FH|prohibited_restricted_authorised_chemicals|no                    |
|PCR-0020779-SAMKGO-FH|physical_form                             |["crystals", "powder"]|
|PCR-0020779-SAMKGO-FH|region_country                            | ["Emea_EU"]          |
+---------------------+------------------------------------------+----------------------+



def string_to_array(c):
    out = eval(c) if c.strip().startswith('[') else [c]
    return out

string_to_array_udf = udf(string_to_array, ArrayType(StringType()))
out_df = df.withColumn("data", string_to_array_udf(col("data"))).withColumn("data", explode_outer("data"))

+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|    identifier_field|              values|    data|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|PCR-0020779-SAMKG...|prohibited_restri...|      no|
|PCR-0020779-SAMKG...|       physical_form|crystals|
|PCR-0020779-SAMKG...|       physical_form|  powder|
|PCR-0020779-SAMKG...|      region_country| Emea_EU|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

Comment: it works great! could you please explain the function?

Comment: It's just the magic of eval function in python - `https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval`

Comment: you should avoid `eval` for security reason.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34904657/2956135 
(use `literal_eval` or `json.loads`)

also, you want to go without `udf` as `udf` is generally inefficient, but if your dataframe is small, this works fine.

Comment: @Emma, yeah we should avoid UDF, but I'm not sure if we have any spark built  in function to do what eval does.

Comment: if we convert it for a pandas df we will be able to solve it efficiently

Comment: hmm, is there workaround without using `eval` and `udf`? best to use `explode` I guess but how do I `cast` Data column from `string` to `array`?

Comment: You can use split function on column data and get an array, but again you have to do lot of cleanups, like remove `[`, double quotes etc

Comment: why not to just change the `datatype`?

Comment: That will not work, you can try - `df.withColumn("data", col("data").cast("array<string>"))`

Comment: `" cannot cast string to array"`, but how can I read the exisitg `df` with custom schema?

Comment: Updated answer - Added without UDF solution

Comment: sorry, did not understand

Comment: I dont see the updated part.